# Matrix reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I can't figure out why this is incorrect

Comment: What do you get when you row reduce the associated matrix?

Comment: I don't understand all you wrote above, but the first vector to the left (the one with an upper entry of 7) solves the system. After that none of the other ones does, and I can't say what does letter s,t,u are.

Comment: @Joanpemo $s,t,u$ are likely intended as parameters.  The final three vectors should span the nullspace of the matrix, whereas the first vector should be the non-homogenous solution to the system.

Comment: I expect that your mistake is that you are missing the equations $x_2=x_2$ and $x_5=x_5$ and $x_6=x_6$ in your system.  If you are parametrizing $s=x_2$ and $t=x_5$, etc... The second vector should not have been $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\0\\0\\\vdots\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ but rather $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\1\\0\\\vdots\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  Similarly for the others.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz , but then none of that assumed base of the homogoneous system's solution space is actually a solution.

Comment: @JMoravitz That was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated augmented matrix is the following:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&2&0&5&2&5\\
0&0&0&-1&-2&4&2\\
1&-2&0&0&7&-6&7\end{array}\right]$

Row reducing:

$\xrightarrow{R_1-R_3\mapsto R_3}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&2&0&5&2&5\\
0&0&0&-1&-2&4&2\\
0&0&2&0&-2&8&-2\end{array}\right]$

$\xrightarrow{R_2\leftrightarrow R_3}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&2&0&5&2&5\\
0&0&2&0&-2&8&-2\\
0&0&0&-1&-2&4&2\\\end{array}\right]$

$\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}R_2\mapsto R_2}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&2&0&5&2&5\\
0&0&1&0&-1&4&-1\\
0&0&0&-1&-2&4&2\\\end{array}\right]$

$\xrightarrow{R_1-2R_2\mapsto R_1}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&0&0&7&-6&7\\
0&0&1&0&-1&4&-1\\
0&0&0&-1&-2&4&2\\\end{array}\right]$

$\xrightarrow{-R_3\mapsto R_3}\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}1&-2&0&0&7&-6&7\\
0&0&1&0&-1&4&-1\\
0&0&0&1&2&-4&-2\\\end{array}\right]$

Interpreting this as a system of equations:

$\begin{cases}x_1-2x_2+7x_5-6x_6=7\\
x_3-x_5+4x_6=-1\\
x_4+2x_5-4x_6=-2\end{cases}$

If we were to parametrize the solutions and set $x_2,x_5,x_6$ as the parameters $s,t,u$ respectively, then we have the system:

$\begin{cases}x_1=7+2s-7t+6u\\
x_3=-1+t-4u\\
x_4=-2+-2t+4u\end{cases}$

Your mistake was in forgetting that you should also include the equations $x_2=s, x_5=t, x_6=u$ as well.

We have as a final answer:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\0\\-1\\-2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}2\\\color{red}{1}\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-7\\0\\1\\-2\\\color{red}{1}\\0\end{bmatrix}+u\begin{bmatrix}6\\0\\-4\\4\\0\\\color{red}{1}\end{bmatrix}$$